# Python working with sockets the method recv

Tags: python, sockets

I'm programming in python with sockets server-client. When I recieve as the server from the client by using the receive function:

```
someSocket.recv()
```

Is there any possibility that receives an unknown object? Or must I have to note the size of the data that I received from the socket?

Comment: What kind of objects do you want to serialize?

Comment: @pasztorpisti I want to check if the data I recv is int or float or string.

Comment: On Python 3, `recv` will return a `bytes` object. On Python 2, it will be a `str` object. If you want other datatypes, you would have to use serialization libraries, like json or pickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple communication you need some kind of serialzation. For simple communication I often convert the socket into a file like object and then I use some textual simple protocol like pickle or json. Either use pickle, or if you want to send human readable text over the wire then send single-line non-wrapped jsons and terminate each object with a newline character. In case of python pickle gives you more freedom as json has some restrictions on what is considered valid data.

Simple pickle and json based server-client examples:

client.py:

```
import socket, pickle

def socket_to_file(sock):
    try:
        sock.settimeout(15)
        return sock.makefile()
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 3005))
    sock = socket_to_file(sock)
    try:
        request = {
            'param0': True,
            'param2': 'sztringecske',
        }
        print 'Sending request: %s' % (request,)
        pickle.dump(request, sock)
        sock.flush()    # important!!!
        response = pickle.load(sock)
        print 'Received response: %s' % (response,)
    finally:
        sock.close()
```

server.py:

```
import socket, pickle

def socket_to_file(sock):
    try:
        client_sock.settimeout(15)
        return sock.makefile()
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listen_sock = socket.socket()
    try:
        listen_sock.bind(('', 3005))
        listen_sock.listen(10)
        client_sock, client_addr = listen_sock.accept()
    finally:
        listen_sock.close()

    try:
        client_sock = socket_to_file(client_sock)
        request = pickle.load(client_sock)
        print 'Request: %s' % (request,)
        response = 'My smart response.'
        print 'Response: %s' % (response,)
        pickle.dump(response, client_sock)
        client_sock.flush()
    finally:
        client_sock.close()
```

json_client.py:

```
import socket, json

def socket_to_file(sock):
    try:
        sock.settimeout(15)
        return sock.makefile()
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 3005))
    sock = socket_to_file(sock)
    try:
        request = {
            'param0': True,
            'param2': 'sztringecske',
        }
        print 'Sending request: %s' % (request,)
        sock.write(json.dumps(request))
        sock.write('\n')
        sock.flush()    # important!!!
        response = json.loads(sock.readline())
        print 'Received response: %s' % (response,)
    finally:
        sock.close()
```

json_server.py:

```
import socket, json

def socket_to_file(sock):
    try:
        client_sock.settimeout(15)
        return sock.makefile()
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listen_sock = socket.socket()
    try:
        listen_sock.bind(('', 3005))
        listen_sock.listen(10)
        client_sock, client_addr = listen_sock.accept()
    finally:
        listen_sock.close()

    try:
        client_sock = socket_to_file(client_sock)
        request = json.loads(client_sock.readline())
        print 'Request: %s' % (request,)
        response = 'My smart response.'
        print 'Response: %s' % (response,)
        client_sock.write(json.dumps(response))
        client_sock.write('\n')
        client_sock.flush()
    finally:
        client_sock.close()
```

How to detect what kind of data you received? The best is if you don't have to detect. With the above solutions you can send complex objects like `{'command': 'delete', 'delete_param': 'delete_specific_param' }`. If you define your protocol so that the message sent to the server always contains the `command` key then the server can always check this and interpret the rest of the data according to the actual command. If you still insist on sending primitive objects like `int`s then after receiving the response you can simply use `isinstance(response, int)` to check whether the response is an integer.

Efficiency: These solutions send textual data over the write but don't be afraid, over-optimized network communication is rarely needed. These solutions are perfect to put together simple client-server thingies.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I understand that you want to know if the data received is an integer or a string. After receiving the data you can assign it to a variable. Then you can use various methods like `isdigit()` and [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)  to know if it is a string, integer or float.

**Example**:

```
Test = "123"
if Test.isdigit() == True:
    print "Test is an integer"
else:
    print "Test is not an integer"
```

If you want to know if it is a float or not then you can try using [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
>>> x = 123
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
>>> y = 123.01
>>> isinstance(y, float)
True
```

You can combine both the methods and create a new method that does this all.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets only send and receive **bytes** objects. You can send objects through sockets with **pickle** (Just remember, pickle is **not** secure). You can test the type the object is by using **isinstance()**:

```
data= sock.recv(1024)
obj= pickle.loads(data)
isInt= isinstance(obj, int)
```

If you want to turn it into a string you will need to decode the byte:

```
data= sock.recv(1024)
strdata= data.decode('utf-8')
```

It is a good practice to receive data in increments of 1024, if you want to send more than that amount then you will have to make a looping structure. Personally, sockets are too low level for me, I use [this](http://mccormick.cx/projects/PodSixNet) simple library for all my networking needs. It claims to be good for games, but It can be used for anything.