# How to make python disregard first couple of lines of a text file

Tags: python, text

I was wondering if it was possible to make python disregard the first 4 lines of my text file. Like if I had a text file which looked like this:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
123412
1232134
```

Can I make it so python starts working from the numbers?

Comment: Sure -- Is it always 4 lines?  Is it only the non-number lines?  What is the criteria for dropping the first 4?

Comment: I only have one file which begins with 4 lines of useless information. I would like to make python completely disregard these lines

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  The question is *how does the program know the lines are useless*?  It it useless because it isn't a number?  Is it useless because it is literally `aaa`?  if it's only 1 file in a bunch, rather than modifying your python, maybe it's better to fix the file:  `tail +4 file > file_new` IIRC.

Comment: Yes it is useless because it isn't a number

Comment: If you want you can check if it is a number or not. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284708/python-working-with-sockets-the-method-recv/22284863#22284863

Answer (score 3):

Use [`next`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and a loop:

```
with open("/path/to/myfile.txt") as myfile:
    for _ in range(4):  # Use xrange here if you are on Python 2.x
        next(myfile)
    for line in myfile:
        print(line)  # Just to demonstrate
```

Because [file objects](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) are iterators in Python, a line will be skipped each time you do `next(myfile)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
f = open('file.txt')
for index,line in enumerate(f):
    if index>3:
      print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you know the number of lines to discard, you can use this method:

```
    for i, line in enumerate(open('myfile')):
        if i < number_of_lines_to_discard:
            continue
        # do your stuff here
```

or if you just want to disregard non numeric lines:

```
    for line in open('myfile'):
        if not re.match('^[0-9]+$\n', line):
             continue
        # do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution, not relying on the exact number of lines:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            line = int(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        # process line
```