# What is an acceptable way to discard the first couple lines of text?

Tags: python, python-requests

Using the requests library, I am **scraping** lines of text off the SEC.gov website for a personal project. I get an error because I am trying to assign to variables before the correct lines are reached. I saw this question which is almost identical.

[How to make python disregard first couple of lines of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417616/how-to-make-python-disregard-first-couple-of-lines-of-a-text-file)

However, I want the program to be able to determine how many lines to skip, not hard code it.

I hardcoded it, but I believe the number of lines could potentially change. Also, I figure I could check the line for the delimiter (|), and if the line does not have it, then throw out the line, but that would mean checking a ridiculous number of characters. The code:

```
try:
    for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)
        lines = r.text.splitlines(True)
        for line in lines[12:]:
            # cik, company_name, filling_type, filling_date, edgar_url = line.split('|')
            # if cik == 729986:
            #     print(line)
```

Is there anyway to have python try an assignment, and if it throws an error, toss it that way? Say,

```
try:
    cik, company_name, filling_type, filling_date, edgar_url = line.split('|')
except Exception as e:
    continue
```

Here are two lines of what would be returned if I can correctly skip the line, as the hard coding does:

```
72971|WELLS FARGO & COMPANY/MN|SC 13G|2019-02-14|edgar/data/72971/0000072971-19-000222.txt

729986|UNITED BANKSHARES INC/WV|10-K|2019-03-01|edgar/data/729986/0001193125-19-060795.txt
```

However, the first 14 lines (I believe) describe the data such as:

```
Retrieved from: SEC.gov, Tuesday April 9th, 2019
Email: ########.gov
```

which makes the following line fail:

```
cik, company_name, filling_type, filling_date, edgar_url = line.split('|')
```

The solution I ended up coding is based on the solution that is marked correct here because I think it is most in line with my original thinking. All the answers have given me something to think about as I continue developing this project. I think each solution has benefits.
Here is my final code, feel free to critique it:

```
try:
    for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)
        lines = r.text.splitlines(True)
        for line in lines[0:]:
            row = line.split('|')
            if len(row) == 5:
                cik, company_name, filling_type, filling_date, edgar_url = row[0:5]
                
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
```

SUPER EDIT:
Is there a way to get the solution to one line: something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([line.split('|') for line in lines if len(line.split('|') == 4])
# I think this calls the split function twice though which might be finicky.
```

Will ask in new question.

Comment: You have put an answer yourself (try except with string split). What is your question?

Comment: @EdwardAung my original solution is this: `try:
    for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)
        lines = r.text.splitlines(True)
        for line in lines[12:]:
            # cik, company_name, filling_type, filling_date, edgar_url = line.split('|')`
 I do not think a try: keyword should be used to skip lines, more to catch errors. However, I do see what you are saying. Is there a failure to assign error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect a total of 5 columns. Ignore every line that does not have 5 columns.

```
import requests

def get_index(year, quarter):
    url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' % (year, quarter)
    r = requests.get(url)

    for line in r.text.splitlines():
        row = line.split('|')
        if len(row) == 5:
            yield row

rows = get_index(2018, 'QTR1')
next(rows)  # skip header row

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    print(row)
    if i > 10:
        break
```

Comment: All the solutions seem pretty good. However, I think this is the best long-term solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()

    # Find the csv header
    m1 = re.search("\\n(\w\s*\|?)+\\n", r.text)

    # Find end of dash line starting from end of header
    start = r.text.find("\n", m1.end()) + 1

    # r.text[start:] is the part of the text after the initial header
    # Get individual lines
    lines = r.text[start:].splitlines()

    # If you have Pandas, you can pack everything into a nice DataFrame    
    cols = m1.group().strip().split('|')
    df = pd.DataFrame([line.split('|') for line in lines], columns=cols)
    return df

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2019/QTR1/master.idx'
df = get_data(url)
df.head()
```

gives

```
       CIK            Company Name Form Type  Date Filed                                     Filename
0  1000045  NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC      10-Q  2019-02-14  edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-19-039489.txt
1  1000045  NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC         4  2019-01-15  edgar/data/1000045/0001357521-19-000001.txt
2  1000045  NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC         4  2019-02-19  edgar/data/1000045/0001357521-19-000002.txt
3  1000045  NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC         4  2019-03-15  edgar/data/1000045/0001357521-19-000003.txt
4  1000045  NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC       8-K  2019-02-01  edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-19-024617.txt
```

Comment: I like this solution and might implement a dataframe so I am thankful for your suggestion.

Comment: Is a dataframe as quick as a list of all the lines? @lightalchemist

Comment: The DataFrame is part of the [Pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Whether it is quicker depends on what operations you wish to perform on the lines. In this case, the lines are broken up into individual fields and Pandas allows you to very quickly search, select, plot, read and write the data. For some operations, it is definitely much faster since 1) some of the core operations are written in C and Cython and 2) it provides better structures (e.g., index) to quickly locate data matching some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for line of only "-" then take rows after

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2018/QTR1/master.idx'
r = requests.get(url).text
records = r.splitlines()
results = []
header = 'CIK|Company Name|Form Type|Date Filed|Filename'
found = False
for row in records:
    if found:
        results.append(row.split('|'))
    if not found and set(row.strip()) == {'-'}:
        found = True
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = header.split('|') )
print(df.head())
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. However, it is possible that a row I do want contains a -, which would throw this off. Maybe JP Morgan Chase is JPMorgan - Chase, for example. Also, I think the chosen solution is a bit more efficient. Your code is very readable though! Thanks.

Comment: No. Because I am using set to make sure the line only had - in it