# Is there a way to use an if and a for loop in the same line that a pandas dataframe is created?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I asked a previous question here [What is an acceptable way to discard the first couple lines of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585346/what-is-an-acceptable-way-to-discard-the-first-couple-lines-of-text/55587839#55587839) that got two interesting answers that made me rethink how to approach the problem. Unless looping through a pandas dataframe is much slower than looping through a bunch of text lines, I see no reason not to use a dataframe.
The code I originally settled on was this:

```
try:
    for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)
        lines = r.text.splitlines(True)
        for line in lines[0:]:
            row = line.split('|')
            if len(row) == 5:
                cik, company_name, filling_type, filling_date, edgar_url = row[0:5]

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
```

However, I figured a pandas would be easier for an end user to use in other methods (hopefully barring a huge performance decrease). I changed my code to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
try:
    for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)
        lines = r.text.splitlines(True)
        for line in lines[0:]:
             row = line.split('|')
             if len(row) == 5:
                 df.append(row)
                 print(df.head(10))
```

which I believe gives me what I want. However is there a way to shorten this even more to something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
try:
    for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)
        lines = r.text.splitlines(True)
        df = pd.DataFrame([line.split('|') for line in lines if len(line.split('|') == 4])
```

I can not say I have seen an if used in the constructor of a dataframe before, and although the code compiles, I seem to get an empty dataframe. I am assuming that 1) calling line.split('|') twice means no lines are returned. Is there a way to keep this as one line? Is this performance as good as just using a huge list?
Thanks for the input.

Comment: That does not give you what you want. `.append` does not work in-place. Note, `.append`ing in a loop is a terrible practice with `pd.Dataframes`, it is highly inefficient

Comment: Anyway, you are showing a list-comprehension. What isn' working? note, you are doing unecessary work simply to avoid a for-loop (i.e. `.split("|")` twice just to get the `len`). Just use your for-loop, but don't `.append` to a dataframe, make a `rows = []` list, and use `row.append(row)` in your loop, then at the end, use `df = pd.DataFrame(rows)`

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to move away from apend because of that reason. My question is how can I make `df = pd.DataFrame([line.split('|') for line in lines if len(line.split('|') == 4])` have only one line.split('|')

Comment: What about `pd.read_csv(sep='|')`?

Comment: @FrickFrack don't use a comprehension, just do a for-loop. Indeed, a big reason that Python 3.8 will have assignment *expressions* is because people do this thing were they would rather use a list-comprehension and make an expensive call twice than the reasonable thing and just using a loop. So either use the loop, or wait for Python 3.8 assignment expressions.

Comment: "I am assuming that 1) calling line.split('|') twice means no lines are returned." No, calling `line.split` twice won't affect anything except being unnecessarily inefficient. Not the biggest deal... but if you are getting an empty data-frame, then the culprit lies elsewhere. EDIT: wait, yeah, because you are doing `df = ...` *inside the loop*, so `df` will only contain the final data-frame (which seems to be empty)

Comment: Like I stated originally, use a `rows = []`, then append *to that list in the loop*, then *outside the loop*, create your data-frame: `df = pd.DataFrame(rows)`. Or use a generator, like your accepted solution in the related question (`pd.DataFrame` accepts a generator)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is a dataframe as quick to go through as going through a filled-in rows would be after `rows.append(row)`

Comment: What do you mean "go through"? What are you trying to do with the data-frame? `pandas` essentially wraps `numpy`, which provides *very fast*, vectorized, numerical operations. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  My code is `for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
        # Make a request to the URL and get the response
        url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/%s/%s/master.idx' %(year, quarter)
        r = requests.get(url)

        lines = r.text.splitlines()
        rows = []
        for line in lines[0:]:
            row = line.split('|')
            if len(row) == 5:
                rows.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True))` as you suggested